# Сменить иконку кнопки которая в кастомном ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Не могу сделать следующее. В общем есть главное MainActivity, в котором через кастомный `ListView` выводится список слов из БД (каждый пункт списка состоит из `TextView` и `ImageButton`) и WordActivity. В WordActivity есть кнопка "Добавить/Удалить из избранного", которая добавляет или удаляет слово из списка избранных. Проблема в следующем. Если в WordActivity удалить слово из списка избранных, и вернуться в MainActivity, то иконка у `ImageButton` в кастомном `ListView` у соответствующего слова не меняется. Как мне добиться того чтобы иконка изменялась?

```
public class WordsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context ctx;
    ArrayList<SingleWord> words;

    //Объект класса SingleWord
    SingleWord p;

    //Конструктор класса WordsAdapter
    WordsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SingleWord> words) {
        ctx = context;
        this.words = words;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return words.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return words.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Переменная типа ViewHolder
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        //Создаем объект типа SingleWord
        p = getSingleWord(position);

        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
            //Создаем объект типа ViewHolder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            //
            viewHolder.txtAlphabet = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAlphabet);
            viewHolder.txtWord = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtWord);
            viewHolder.btnFavorites = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnFavorites);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //Вставляем в соответствующие TextView и ImageButton данные из класса SingleWord
        viewHolder.txtWord.setText(p.word);
        viewHolder.txtAlphabet.setText(p.alphabet);
        viewHolder.btnFavorites.setImageResource(p.bntIcon);
        viewHolder.btnFavorites.setFocusable(false);

        //Проверяем если значение favorites из класса SingleWord = 1, то одна иконки, иначе другая
        if (words.get(position).getFavorites().equals("1")) {
            viewHolder.btnFavorites.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_yellow);
        } else if (words.get(position).getFavorites().equals("0")) {
            viewHolder.btnFavorites.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_outline_black);
        }

        //Событие клика на кнопку "Добавить в избранное"
        viewHolder.btnFavorites.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String selectedItem = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if (selectedItem.equals("что-то")) {
                    //Проверяем опять переменную favorites
                    if (words.get(position).getFavorites().equals("1")) {
                        String wordStr = viewHolder.txtWord.getText().toString();
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put(SlovarEntry.COLUMN_FAVORITES, "0");

                        // Вставляем новый ряд в базу данных и запоминаем его идентификатор
                        long newRowId = db.database.update(SlovarEntry.TABLE_RUS, values, SlovarEntry.COLUMN_WORD + "= ?", new String[]{wordStr});
                        words.get(position).setFavorites("0");
                        // Выводим сообщение в успешном случае или при ошибке
                        if (newRowId == -1) { // Если ID  -1, значит произошла ошибка
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Удалено из избранное", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            viewHolder.btnFavorites.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_outline_black);
                        }
                    } else if (words.get(position).getFavorites().equals("0")){
                        String wordStr = viewHolder.txtWord.getText().toString();
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put(SlovarEntry.COLUMN_FAVORITES, "1");

                        // Вставляем новый ряд в базу данных и запоминаем его идентификатор
                        long newRowId = db.database.update(SlovarEntry.TABLE_RUS, values, SlovarEntry.COLUMN_WORD + "= ?", new String[]{wordStr});
                        words.get(position).setFavorites("1");
                        // Выводим сообщение в успешном случае или при ошибке
                        if (newRowId == -1) { // Если ID  -1, значит произошла ошибка
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Добавлено в избранное", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            viewHolder.btnFavorites.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_yellow);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    SingleWord getSingleWord(int position) {
        return ((SingleWord) getItem(position));
    }
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtAlphabet;
    TextView txtWord;
    ImageButton btnFavorites;
}
```